# JSON Problemas para recuperar valores

Tags: php, json, api, libcurl

Bom galera, eu sou meio noob nesse assunto de php, estou desenvolvendo um site dinamico que os videos estão em outro servidor por tanto estou usando a API desse site, tenho problemas quando estou realizando um chamado do JSON ja decodificado para fazer um loop de um iframe, ele nao me imprime nehum resultado, deixo o codigo para vcs observarem, muito obrigado

```php
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$apiToken = 'zAt7UIgedZtnicMwvKRV1gz39vYlBKEshHQRpOVWahQn4dRyEhLFTF5qJ6ad';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.vidoza.net/v1/files");
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ".$apiToken; 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization )); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($res["data"], true);

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    echo '
        <IFRAME
            SRC="https://vidoza.net/embed-'.$value["id"].'.html"
            FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 
            SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=640 HEIGHT=360 allowfullscreen>
         </IFRAME>
    ';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez você esteja tendo problemas com a [configuração](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/) do php para acessar url com SSL.

Experimente realizar a requisição desativando essa verificação com:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`

Você também está realizando o json_decode de forma incorreta. O decode deve ser feito diretamente no resultado bruto.

O código final ficou da seguinte forma:

```php
<?php

$ch         = curl_init();
$apiToken       = 'SEU TOKEN AQUI';
$authorization  = "Authorization: Bearer ".$apiToken; 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.vidoza.net/v1/files");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authorization )); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($res, true);
curl_close($ch);


foreach ($json['data'] as $key => $value) {
    echo'

    <IFRAME
        SRC="https://vidoza.net/embed-'.$value["id"].'.html"
        FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 
        SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=640 HEIGHT=360 allowfullscreen>
     </IFRAME>
    ';
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Vinicius, era isso mesmo, lhe agradeço muito o tempo dedicado...